# MS Project - Adding multiples of the same resources to multiple concurrent tasks

Tags: project-management, ms-project, resource-management

I'm currently working on a project within MS Project and have most aspects covered apart from resources. I want to add multiple versions of the same resource (in this case a generic employee) to some tasks. I also have concurrent tasks which these generic employees will also be working on but I don't want this to count towards the total resource count. In short, I want to use the same resource multiple times each on 3 concurrent tasks which share resources. Is this possible in MS Project 2013?

Here's the context which will hopefully help: I'm currently working on a project to set up a conference. I have around 10 employees who are each on the same wage ($ per hour). I have 3 tasks running concurrently during the conference as follows ; Hand out brochures to patrons, Enforce rules and regulations and Be on hand at all times during the conference. I want the same 10 employees to work on all 3 of these tasks at once and to be paid only once for doing them all concurrently. Is there a way to specify this in MS Project? I've tried simply assigning the same employee resource object to the same task multiple times but it doesn't seem to like that. Should I just create 10 generic employees ('employee 1', 'employee 2' etc) and assign them to them all? If so, how then would you ensure that the employees are paid the same for doing all 3 tasks?

I hope I have provided enough clarification.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these employees are interchangeable, set up ONE resource and set the Max Units to 10. Then assign as many of those resources as you want to each of the three concurrent tasks.